# How to lay out Composables relative to a view/Y position?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-constraintlayout

I want to lay out some Composables relative to another view.

This view is a `View` (traditional views), which I'm thinking of passing itself or its Y position to the composable. Then the composable can try to position its subcomponents relative to that view/Y position.

I could just constrain my `ComposeView` and `View` within the XML `ConstraintLayout`, but this causes other issues. It's a bit of a long story which I don't want to get into though.

Is it possible to tell composables to constrain itself to a traditional view, without doing it in XML?

Comment: Wait you say you don't wanna use XML, and that you're using `ComposeView` at the same time? Oh you're using the traditional view system but designing the UI programmatically, I guess. Babe if that's all you want, why not switch to Compose? Life's easier with Compose and as much as anyone hates typing out/reading, *the whole story*, it is often, sadly, crucial to finding the optimum approach to the problem.

Comment: Sadly I'm working on a project that uses `ExoPlayer` and I've tried to migrate some player UI components to compose but it doesn't look like it works. So I'm forced to do interop.

Comment: Tbf it is so easy with Compose that I'd probably implement my own player, but as my father used to say, no two snow flakes are alike. You do you babes.